# Excel VBA: need more efficient solution to sorting this matrix into new matrices based on values of first column - takes too long

Tags: excel, vba

Excel novice here.

I'm trying to sort a long matrix of data into new matrices based on values in the first column. For example, if 10,000 rows have "a" in their first column, I make a new matrix with those 10,000 rows. I do this for "b" as well.

Right now, the code is just a loop that looks at every single row and copies it to the side if it meets the criteria. Then I copy and paste the matrix "b" so that it's adjacent to matrix "a".

Ugly, right? I have 70000-100000 rows to work with, so this makes things kind of slow. What is a more elegant solution?

```
Dim daRow As Long
daRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
Dim cell As Range
Dim rRange As Range
Set rRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(daRow, 9))

For Each cell In rRange
If cell.Value = "a" Then
cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = cell.Value
cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
ElseIf cell.Value = "b" Then
cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = cell.Value
cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
cell.Offset(0, 10).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
End If
Next cell

Dim theRow As Long
theRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(theRow + 1, 17), Cells(theRow + theRow, 19)).Cut
Range("Q1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Sort by the first column using the range `.Sort` method, then copy the sub-range(s) and paste as needed. Doing this row-by-row is, as you observe, inefficient.

Comment: Could you point me to some literature on .Sort and copying the sub-ranges?

Comment: Use the macro recorder to sort your range; modify the resulting code as needed. "Sort" is in the Data ribbon: http://imgur.com/6bjRxxc

Comment: I agree with @DavidZemens.  Try a sort + autofilter solution, it will take almost no time to run.  Recording a macro should get you well over 75% of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider pulling in all data in one VBA instruction and putting it all out in just one more. That way it'll be much faster. Every time your code reads or writes from the spreadsheet, there is a massive overhead.

E.g. Replace all instances of .Cell() in the following way

For e.g. code such as the following

```
For i = 1 to 10
   Variable = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Cell(i,1).Value
Next i
```

can be replaced by

```
Dim VariantArray as Variant
VariantArray = Workeheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

' Now VariantArray(0,0) has the first element, (1,0) has the second, etc.
```

Similarly, while putting it all back, create a variant array and stuff it with all the data you need for your matrix such that `OutputArray(0,0)` is the top left cell value, etc. and then use

```
Dim OutputRange as Range
Set OutputRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:Z300") ' Or wherever you like it
OutputRange = OutputArray
```